# Raising & lowering indices of 3-pseudovectors?

Tags: metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, conventions, covariance

Now, let space tmie metric is $$\eta_{\mu\nu}=\text{diag}(+,-,-,-)$$
now
$$x_{\mu}=(x^0,-\mathbf{x})$$ and $$x^{\mu}=(x^0,\mathbf{x})$$

and $$x^{\mu}=\eta^{\mu\nu}x_{\nu}$$

also $$\partial_\mu=(\partial^0,\nabla)$$
and finally $$\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\lambda}$$ is totally anti symmetric tensor
with  $$\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\lambda}=-\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\lambda}$$
now by using this rules i am trying to describe electromagnetic thoery covariantly.

also notice that $$x_i=-\mathbf{x}_{i}$$

we have $$F^{i,0}=E^{i}$$
now the thing i got confused is, $$E^{i}=E_{i}$$ and $$B^{i}=B_{i}$$

also $$\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_{j}A^{k}=B_i$$

now these last two formulas are confusing because, when i have $B$ and $E$ the usual raising and lowering does not work they do not change sign . also How does raising and lowering works for $$\epsilon_{ijk}$$ I know what happens for  $$\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\lambda}$$  but not $$\epsilon_{ijk}$$ is $\epsilon_{ijk}$ totaly antwi symmetric tensor or what?

Comment: Yes the Levi-Civita tensor, regardless of it's rank, is completely anti-symmetric.

Comment: I think he meant to ask whether $\epsilon_{ijk} = \pm \epsilon^{ijk}$. Can you clarify, op, what is the specific doubt you are having?

Comment: Well, if that's the case then $\epsilon _{ijk} = \epsilon ^{ijk}$ always. Since covariant and contraviant vectors are the same in the Euclidean geometry. The same would hold for any number of raising or lowering.

Comment: @thunderbolt but we definitely have $A^i=-A_i$

Comment: @physshyp If A denotes the (three-dimensional) magnetic vector potential then $A_i = A^i$. What you said is true for the four-potential.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what the question is, but you're definitely wandering off track when you  write things like $E^i=E_i$. The electric and magnetic fields are not vectors. Together, they're part of the electromagnetic field tensor, which is rank 2. Why does the title talk about "3-pseudovectors?" AFAIK the standard definition of a pseudovector is that it doesn't change under parity. Is that what you mean, or do you mean "something that's not really a vector?"

Comment: @BenCrowell  the thing is some one changed the title my question is how raising lowering works for 3 comoponent vectors like electric field. alsp $\epsilon$ changes sign when i raise and lower all of the indices in 4 indice version. is that true for 3 indice version .

Comment: @MannyC thats the exact doubt  i have. how do you raise lover anti symmetric tensors indices if we have 3 indices instead of 4. also how do you raise lower, electric and magnetic field indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case for antisymmetric tensors is not different from other generic tensors. Normally one has
$$
T_{\mu_1\cdots \mu_k} = \eta_{\mu_1\nu_1}\cdots  \eta_{\mu_k\nu_k} T^{\nu_1\cdots \nu_k}\,.
$$
If you have a totally antisymmetric tensor this simplifies to
$$
\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\lambda} = \det(\eta) \,\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\lambda}\,.
$$
And since $\eta = \mathrm{diag}(1,-1,-1,-1)$ you get the minus, the same would be true for the mostly plus metric (in any even dimension). For the electric field one has to be precise with the definition
$$
E^i \equiv F^{i0}\,,\qquad E_i \equiv F_{i0}\,.
$$
And you can see that for lowering the $i$ index you pay the price of a minus sign. The same would be true for a mostly plus metric but the sign comes from the $0$.

Finally the $\epsilon_{ijk}$. If you define
$$
\epsilon_{ijk} \equiv \epsilon_{0ijk}\,,\qquad \epsilon^{ijk} \equiv \epsilon^{0ijk} =  \eta^{00}\eta^{i l} \eta^{jm}\eta^{kn} \epsilon_{lmn}\,, \tag{1}\label{1}
$$
then the upper and the lower index version differ in sign. If you instead define
$$
\epsilon^{ijk} = \eta^{i l} \eta^{jm}\eta^{kn} \epsilon_{lmn}\,, \tag{2}\label{2}
$$
then the relative sign depends on whether you use mostly plus $(+)$ or mostly minus $(-)$ signature. This is not an ambiguity. If you use either definition consistently, when you decompose any four-vector expression into a time and a three-dimensional part you'll get the same result.

For example, $B$ can be defined as
$$
\tilde{F}^{\mu\nu} \equiv -\tfrac12 \epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\lambda} F_{\rho\lambda}\,,\qquad B^i \equiv \tilde{F}^{i0}\,,\qquad B_i \equiv \tilde{F}_{i0}\,.
$$
And it also changes sign as any other (presudo)vector. Its decomposition into time and 3d part is
$$
B^i =  \tfrac12 \epsilon^{0ijk} F_{jk} = s \tfrac12 \epsilon^{ijk} F_{jk}\,,\;\;\qquad B_i = \tfrac12 \epsilon_{0ijk} F^{jk} =  \tfrac12 \epsilon_{ijk} F^{jk} \,,
$$
where $s=1$ for the definition \eqref{1} and $\eta^{00}$ for the definition \eqref{2}. You can see that, not matter what, $B^i = - B_i$ (in any signature).

---

Note that if you are in Euclidean space to start with (i.e. you are not in an Euclidean subspace of Minkowski), then the natural metric is the all-plus $\delta_{ij}$, obviously. Therefore the Levi-Civita tensor with upper and lower indices will have the same sign $\epsilon_{i_1\ldots i_n} = \epsilon^{i_1\ldots i_n}$.

Comment: great answer in my calculations for $E$ and  $B$ i did not changed sign while raising and lowering. on the other hand I also did the same mistake with $\epsilon^{ijk}$ thus at the end my result were correct(agreed with litreture).  thanks a lot i will go through my calculations again and fix those mistakes.

Comment: Maybe you just defined that $E_i = E^i$. That's still correct as long as you are consistent (e.g. you have to say $E_i = - F_{i0}$).

Comment: well thats exactly what i am doing

Comment: if i define $E_i=E^i$ wouldn't I violate raising and lowering rule, in + --- metric.

Comment: $E$ is not a four-vector, so you have a bit of freedom on how to relate it to four-vector quantities. You just have to be consistent.